# How to store a map on disk with mule esb?

Tags: java, mule, esb

I have defined a map in Mule ESB:

```
<spring:bean name="requestsMap" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="singleton"/>
```

I need to store this map on disk so that application/server crash wont harm the data inside the map. but i cant find out how?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [file-endpoint](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Connector). The documentation also includes more complete [examples](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Transport+Reference).

Just set the map as the payload before the file endpoint.

Comment: thank you. can you provide a code snippet for comprehensive answer?

Comment: I don't have mule nor mulestudio installed on this machine, but I included a link to examples in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, give a try to the [FileHashMap](http://software.clapper.org/javautil/api/org/clapper/util/misc/FileHashMap.html) of the **org.clapper** javautil. It stores the map data into a file. Your spring bean declaration should be something like:

```
<spring:bean name="requestsMap" class="org.clapper.util.misc.FileHashMap">
      <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="filepath"/>
   </spring:bean>
```

(Code not tested)

Insert the following dependency in maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.clapper</groupId>
  <artifactId>javautil</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and the repository:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
    </releases>
    <id>clapper-org-maven-repo</id>
    <name>org.clapper Maven Repo</name>
    <url>http://maven.clapper.org/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
  ...
</repositories>
```

I think the implementation is not thread-safe (I am not sure), so be careful to use it as a singleton.

Check the library [website](http://software.clapper.org/javautil/index.html) for more information. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use MapDB: http://www.mapdb.org/

Comment: some how i choose your way. but instead i used LevelDB

Comment: but it is not directly within mules config file, i am using some other spring beans to achieve the goal

Answer (score 0):

Using a file outbound endpoint will store the payload in a file:

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="/somePath" responseTimeout="10000" />
```

but this will be performed at some point in your flow, so that if the machine crashed before that point the map won't be saved.

For this kind of requirements is better to use persistent storages, please provide some context about your app to see how to use them.

Regards,
Marcos

Comment: how are you suggesting to bind the map with this file:outbound-endpoint?

Comment: No. If you have a map I think you need "something" that maps keys to values, this can be accomplished by using a mule object store. These stores can by persistent what means the information they hold survives system shutdowns. Please take a loot at: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Object+Stores for more info. Besides, share more details about how are you using your map for a better understanding. Regards, Marcos.